# OpenShift Gradle fails with java.net.BindException: Permission denied

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, openshift

I am on OpenShift and using Gradle. I am running into an issue where I get the below exception. I tried Gradle 1.6 and Gradle 1.11 but no luck. Some minimal partial answers are covered on the web but none of them worked for instance I tried adding `-Dorg.gradle.bindaddress=$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP` but that has no effect. This is a deal breaker for me right now. Any pointers/help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
23:52:49.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
23:52:49.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:38)
23:52:49.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 44 more`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are basically running into this bug - http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2871.
I don't think there is a solution for this right now. Setting *org.gradle.bindaddress* sounds good, and there is indeed a pull request to add such a property to Gradle (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/242), but this code is not merged.

Comment: Indeed. I'm running into GRADLE-2871. And due to that Gradle cannot be used on OpenShift. Such a deal breaker.